# com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: timeout: socket is not established

Tags: java, sockets, sftp, jsch

I am trying to upload a file to a server (with java) where I have an acount and the SFTP connection stopped working (for a timeout problem I guess). I want to know is there a way to reset this connection and get it working. This is the function:

```
    public static void upload(File file, boolean retry) {
    try 
    {
        System.out.println("Uplodaing file " + file.getName());

        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession("****", "*****", 22);
        session.setPassword("*****");

        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.setTimeout(5);

        System.out.println("Establishing connection");
        session.connect(10);


        Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;

        if (!retry)
            sftpChannel.put(file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(),new SystemOutProgressMonitor(), ChannelSftp.OVERWRITE);
        else
            sftpChannel.put(file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(),new SystemOutProgressMonitor(), ChannelSftp.RESUME);

        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        upload(file, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: *"SFTP connection stopped working"* - That particular connection? Or you cannot (re)connect at all?

Comment: I cannot reconnect to the server that am working on or even a test server.

Comment: Not even with a standalone SFTP client?

Comment: Yes, in fact I tried with winscp and I couldn't connect

Comment: Oh wait sorry I managed to connect via winscp but the error now becomes:

Comment: No sorry I managed to connect to another server via winscp but the problem in eclipse is the same

Comment: I got lost, keep only the comments that are correct, remove the rest. Actually you should edit the information into the question. So again, can you clearly answer, whether you can connect with WinSCP (or any other SFTP client) to the server, from the same machine that runs your JSch code, at the same time the JSch cannot connect?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is quite old but in case anyone stumbles over it (as I did):
The problem is the connection timeout, which should be in milliseconds. In case OP intended 10 seconds, it should be 10000 here. 10 milliseconds simply isn't enough.